# Why is memset's value int and not uint8_t?

Tags: c++, c

Sorry for the silly question, may be a duplicate.

So [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) is defined as:

```
void * memset(void * ptr, int value, size_t num);
```

However, we all know that *memset* sets bytes of *ptr* to *value*. My question is, why is *value* defined as *int* when it will be interpreted as *uint8_t*?

Is it due to some legacy compatibility or *int* actually makes sense in a way I can't comprehend? :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for finding the original questions. Can I delete my post?